# SQL add string end of value

Tags: sql

I have a email column and each row has different number of email. I want to add same email end of to each row.
For example;

```
1.abc@hotmail.com;cd@hotmail.com
2.def@hotmail.com
3.a@hotmail.com;b@hotmail.com;d@hotmail.com
```

.
.
.
What I want is;

```
1.abc@hotmail.com;cd@hotmail.com;newemail@hotmail.com
2.def@hotmail.com;newemail@hotmail.com
3.a@hotmail.com;b@hotmail.com;d@hotmail.com;newemail@hotmail.com
```

how can I add ?

Comment: Never, ever store data as semicolon separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add your own table and column names but it sounds like a simple update

```
update tablename set column = column + ';newemail@hotmail.com'
```

If you only want certain rows updated then add a:

```
where column like '%search condition%'
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any information about database (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.). My solution is for SQL Server

```
update [tablename] set [column] = concat([column] + ';', 'newemail@hotmail.com')
```

Why using `concat` and "+"? Beacause if your table has record with **column** set to **null** then operation `column + ';'` returns also **null**. After that concat **null** with string give you that string so you avoid placing unnecesery semicolon at the begining in this case. If column in row has no **null** in **column** then `column + ';'` will add semicolon before your new email address.